# How to pass argument for the apple script

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I have following script :)

```
property word_docs : {"org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", "com.microsoft.word.doc"}
property default_path : (path to desktop) as alias
property Delim : {".docx", ".doc"}
property PDF : ".pdf"

set outPDF to {}

set selected_files to (choose file of type word_docs default location default_path with multiple selections allowed without invisibles and showing package contents)

set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, Delim}
repeat with afile in selected_files
    copy item 1 of text items of (afile as text) & PDF to the end of outPDF
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID


tell application id "com.microsoft.Word"
    activate
    repeat with i from 1 to count of selected_files
        open (item i of selected_files)
        set theOutputPath to (item 1 of outPDF)
        -- close access (open for access exportDocument)
        tell active document
            save as it file name theOutputPath file format format PDF
            close saving no
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
return
```

That helps me convert doc & docx files -> pdf, but it is too interactive.

And I have idea to run this script via terminal and i want to pass file path or directory as argument
for example:

```
$ script /Users/test/dest_dir/ /Users/test/out_dir/
```

will produce all pdf files into out_dir.

I saw this library also but it converts only docx files:
https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/

Is there anyone here who can help me rewrite this script .. I don't understand this language at all. or maybe someone will point to the finished tool. I need to do this on the mac os operating system.

Comment: This might help. Here's my article with the original Microsoft AppleScript documentation that they released with Office 2008: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2020/10/office-applescript-reference-cool-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050523140439734

argv is an array of arguments in string format

```
on run argv
    return item 1 of argv
```